# How can I convert this binary recursive function into a tail-recursive form?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree, tail-recursion

There is a clear way to convert binary recursion to tail recursion for sets closed under a function, i.e. integers with addition for the Fibonacci sequence:

(Using Haskell)

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib n = fib' 0 1 n

fib' :: Int -> Int -> Int
fib' x y n
    | n < 1 = y  
    | otherwise = fib' y (x + y) (n - 1)
```

This works because we have our desired value, `y`, and our operation, `x + y`, where `x + y` returns an integer just like `y` does.

However, what if I want to use a set that is not closed under a function? I want to take a function that splits a list into two lists and then does the same to those two lists (i.e. like recursively creating a binary tree), where I stop when another function magically says when to stop when it looks at the resulting split:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5]] -> [[1, 3], [4], [2], [5]]
```

That is,

```
splitList :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
splitList intList
    | length intList < 2    = [intList]
    | magicFunction x y > 0 = splitList x ++ splitList y
    | otherwise             = [intList]
  where
    x = some sublist of intList
    y = the other sublist of intList
```

Now, how can this binary recursion be converted to tail recursion? The prior method won't explicitly work, as (`Int + Int -> Int` is the same as the inputs) but (`Split [Int] -/> [[Int]]` is not the same as the input). As such, the accumulator would need to be changed (I assume).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a general trick to make *any* function tail recursive: rewrite it in continuation-passing style (CPS). The basic idea behind CPS is that every function takes an additional parameter--a function to call when they're done. Then, instead of returning a value, the original functions calls the function that was passed in. This latter function is called a "continuation" because it *continues* the computation on to its next step.

To illustrate this idea, I'm just going to use your function as an example. Note the changes to the type signature as well as the structure of the code:

```
splitListCPS :: [Int] -> ([[Int]] -> r) -> r
splitListCPS intList cont
  | length intList < 2    = cont [intList]
  | magicFunction x y > 0 = splitListCPS x $ \ r₁ -> 
                              splitListCPS y $ \ r₂ -> 
                                cont $ r₁ ++ r₂
  | otherwise             = cont [intList]
```

You can then wrap this up into a normal-looking function as follows:

```
splitList :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
splitList intList = splitListCPS intList (\ r -> r)
```

If you follow the slightly convoluted logic, you'll see that these two functions are equivalent. The tricky bit is the recursive case. There, we *immediately* call `splitListCPS` with `x`. The function `\ r₁ -> ...` that tells `splitListCPS` what to do when it's done--in this case, call `splitListCPS` with the next argument (`y`). Finally, once we have both results, we just combine the results and pass that into the original continuation (`cont`). So at the end, we get the same result we had originally (namely `splitList x ++ splitList y`) but instead of returning it, we just use the continuation.

Also, if you look through the above code, you'll note that all the recursive calls are in tail position. At each step, our last action is always either a recursive call or using the continuation. With a clever compiler, this sort of code can actually be fairly efficient.

In a certain sense, this technique is actually similar to what you did for `fib`; however, instead of maintaining an accumulator value we sort of maintain an accumulator of the *computation* we're doing.

Comment: In my experience, multiple-branch recursive functions in GHC are more efficient than their CPS or tail-recursive (with explicit stack) counterparts. Try comparing the computation times of `fib 40` for these 3 styles, for example.

Comment: I wonder, isn't it just out of the frying pan into the fire? We get tail recursion, yes, but instead of keeping values on the stack, we keep them as lambda abstractions on the heap, which could be actually more expensive during runtime.

Comment: Our helper lambda function here is ([[Int]] -> r), but my splitting function splits [Int] into a list with the split, [[Int], [Int]]. How can I then have (\r -> x), which is of type [[Int]] -> [Int]?

Comment: @haskelline

Unfortunately, this list is very large, so the multiple branch recursion would result in a stack size overflow, which is why I need to convert the algorithm to tail recursion which I can then hopefully make strict with bang patterns for the accumulator (which I guess is the lambda function here).

Comment: In fact, this is where I get stuck--if I had a function that has the form [[Int]] -> [[Int]], i.e. it will be closed under [[Int]], then I would be fine. However, my function that creates x and y has the form [Int] -> [[Int]], so the continuation passing style has to be modified in some way, or the function that is passed down cannot be the splitting function.

Comment: @user1104160: That was a typo. I meant to have the function `(\ r -> r)` or just `id`.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis That did it, thank you! Now, to make the function strict, I should just use a bang pattern on const, correct?

Comment: @user1104160: Honestly, I'm not entirely sure what the best way to make your function strict would be, or if it even needs to be strict. You should ask that as a separate question so maybe somebody else can answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't generally want *tail-recursion* in Haskell. What you do want, is *productive corecursion* (see also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/196827/58561)), describing what in [SICP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs) is called an *iterative process*.

You can fix the *type inconsistency* in your function by enclosing initial input in a list. In your example

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5]] -> [[1, 3], [4], [2], [5]]
```

only the first arrow is inconsistent, so change it into

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] -> [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5]] -> [[1, 3], [4], [2], [5]]
```

which illustrates the process of iteratively applying `concatMap splitList1`, where

```
   splitList1 xs 
      | null $ drop 1 xs = [xs]
      | magic a b > 0    = [a,b]    -- (B)
      | otherwise        = [xs]
     where (a,b) = splitSomeHow xs
```

You want to stop if no `(B)` case was fired at a certain iteration.

(edit: removed the intermediate version)

But it is much better to produce the portions of the output that are ready, as soon as possible:

```
splitList :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
splitList xs = g [xs]   -- explicate the stack
  where
    g []                  = []
    g (xs : t)
       | null $ drop 1 xs = xs : g t
       | magic a b > 0    = g (a : b : t)
       | otherwise        = xs : g t
     where (a,b) = splitSomeHow xs 
           -- magic a b = 1
           -- splitSomeHow = splitAt 2
```

Don't forget to compile with `-O2` flag.

Comment: This solution is very aware of Haskell conventions that I do not normally use but should--right down to the Either types. My question is, tail recursion and corecursion are obviously very similar, even as a subset of the other to an extent. Which is better practice in Haskell? The Haskell community seems to favor tail recursion to bypass any stack size overflows, while this solution seems to be only very loosely recursive (the until statement hints of a "while" type of algorithm). Which should be standard practice in this case (to best avoid thunk build-ups)?

Comment: `Either` is nothing special; I just had to tag list element with "process/do not process further" tags. We could use `(0,)` or `(1,)` for that too, although using `Either` seems "cleaner". As for tail recursion, it depends. It is only better if you calculate something as a whole, which can not be calculated by portions - in which case, TR is worse than "guarded recursion"/"corecursion". Whatever the term, the essence is to get iterative, *online* process with minimal stack use that starts producing parts of output as soon as possible. Code here is only a start, first half-step.

Comment: @user1104160 the key is split: do you have to have the whole input to split, or is something like `splitAt 10` enough (which would consume 10 elements of the input list and return `(a,b)` where `b` is portion of input still not accessed. Now, **your `magic` actually is the key** - it demands the rest of list, `b`. So, the question becomes, does it need all of the rest of the list, or is there some number of elements that is enough, and you can work by portions of input list? If not, there will be big memory use, if the list is big.

Comment: The `magic` function requires the entire list, there is absolutely no way around that. In addition, the lists are incredibly huge (they are matrices in the actual algorithm), filled with millions of rows and thousands of columns (although the matrix is sparse, so many columns are condensed). As such, low stack and memory usage is the goal, hence the optimization which I thought would be of the tail recursion form.

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of available memory and the matrix is sparse and so is able to be quite efficiently manipulated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29815/discussion-between-will-ness-and-user1104160)